# Single modal pulling data from inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a single modal that pulls dynamic data from an ng-repeat (`work in workList`) in AngularJS. In other words, the modal does not live within the ng-repeat in order to prevent multiple modals from generating when I can just add dynamic content to one modal. Here's my view:

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
   <div ng-repeat="work in workList"
   //some other code here...
   <div ng-controller="modalController">
      <button ng-click="open_modal(work)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <h2>
   {{ timechosen.data.name }}
   </h2>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's my `modalController`:

```
angular
  .module('testApp')
  .controller('modalController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.open_modal = function(time_chosen) {
      $scope.timechosen = time_chosen.data;
    }
  }])
```

In my modal, `{{ timechosen.data.name }}` does not display anything and I'm pretty sure it's a nesting scope issue because when I set `$scope.timechosen` in my `mainController`, it seems to work fine. However, I do need to set `$scope.timechosen` in the modalController but can't seem to find a way around the possible nested scope issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about putting everything inside a single controller? Like this:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('TestController', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {
        label: 'Item 1',
        body: 'This is the body of item 1',
        title: 'This is number 1'
      },
      {
        label: 'Item 2',
        body: 'This is the body of item 2',
        title: 'This is number 2'
      },
      {
        label: 'Item 3',
        body: 'This is the body of item 3',
        title: 'This is number 3'
      }
    ]
  
    $scope.changeModalInfo = function(info) {
      $scope.info = info;
    }
  });
```

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
        ng-click="changeModalInfo(item)">
      {{item.label}}
    </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div class="modal fade"
      id="myModal" 
      tabindex="-1" 
      role="dialog" 
      aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{info.title}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{info.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you need to break into more than one controller, you can use services or $rootScope (not advised).

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ModalController', function($scope, ModalService) {
    $scope.modal = ModalService;
  })
  .controller('TestController', function($scope, ModalService) {
    $scope.items = [
      {
        label: 'Item 1',
        body: 'This is the body of item 1',
        title: 'This is number 1'
      },
      {
        label: 'Item 2',
        body: 'This is the body of item 2',
        title: 'This is number 2'
      },
      {
        label: 'Item 3',
        body: 'This is the body of item 3',
        title: 'This is number 3'
      }
    ]
  
    $scope.changeModalInfo = function(info) {
      ModalService.info = info;
    }
  })
  .service('ModalService', function() {
    return {};
  });
```

```css
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
        ng-click="changeModalInfo(item)">
      {{item.label}}
    </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="modal fade"
      id="myModal" 
      tabindex="-1" 
      role="dialog" 
      aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
      ng-controller="ModalController as ctrl">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{modal.info.title}}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{modal.info.body}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```